# How to use start_at() & end_at() in Firebase query with Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase realtime database schema:

[image: schema]

Let's suppose above Firebase database schema.
I want to get data with `order_by_key()` which after first 5 and before first 10 not more. Range should be 5-10. Like in the image.

My key is always starting with `-`.

I'm trying this but failed. It returns 0. How can I do this?

```
snapshot = ref.child('tracks').order_by_key().start_at('-\5').end_at(u'-\10').get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase queries are based on cursor/anchor values, and not on offsets. This means that the `start_at` and `end_at` calls expect values of the thing you order on, so in your keys they expect the keys of those notes.

To get the slice you indicate you'll need:

```
ref.child('tracks').order_by_key().start_at('-MQJ7P').end_at(u'-MQJ8O').get()
```

If you don't know either of those values, you can't specify them and can only start from the first item or end on the last item.

The only exception is that you can specify a `limit_to_first` instead of `end_at` to get a number of items at the start of the slice:

```
ref.child('tracks').order_by_key().start_at('-MQJ7P').limit_to_first(5).get()
```

Alternatively if you know only the key of the last item, you can get the five items before that with:

```
ref.child('tracks').order_by_key().end_at('-MQJ8O').limit_to_last(5).get()
```

But you'll need to know at least one of the keys, typically because you've shown it as the last item on the previous page/first item on the next page.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i will query this data hundreds of times. That's why i need to query with range. Like 5-10 or 15-60

Comment: Firebase queries are based on cursor/anchor values, and not on offsets. But once you know the key to start or end at, you can get a range/slide of data. I recommend trying the code in my answer on your data, and reporting back with how it works.

Comment: Hey Frank, sorry for this but it's not useful for me. It cannot do the operation I want.

Comment: That's because the database doesn't work with offsets, but with cursor/anchor values. While it may not be what you hoped for, what I explained is the idiomatic way to implement pagination on Firebase. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯